# Pipes & xargs => top

Tags: macos, xargs

I am trying to use pipes and xargs to start top with a particular pid, but I cannot get it to work and I don't know why:

```
ps aux|grep ProgramName|awk '{print $2}'|head -n1|xargs top -pid
```

I get the correct pid printed to screen if I stop after *head -n1*, and manually adding that pid to the command *top -pid XXX* also works, but running the whole line as one command just does not return the top screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDITs: yes, "-pid" is indeed correct (further checking the remote shell revealed it is actually a Mac OS based system, not a Linux one)

Comment: Remove 'id' from that -p flag and try again.

Answer (score 3):

> > *What am I doing wrong here?*

Several things:

1. You are using `grep` and `awk` in the same pipeline. Since `awk` does pattern matching, there is no reason to use `grep` as a separate process.
2. You are using `awk` and `head` in the same pipeline. Since `awk` can control the number of items it prints, there is no need to use `head`.
3. Your `grep` command will find both the indicated program, *and* the `grep` program.
4. You are using `xargs` to provide a single command line argument. Either backticks or `$()` is a better choice.
5. `top` takes a `-p` switch, not a `-pid` switch. (At least on my computer.)

Adding it all up, try:

```
$ top -p $(ps aux | awk '/ProgramName/ && ! /awk/ { print $2; exit; }')
```

Comment: mh, that does not work. "-pid" is indeed my top's option, not "-p"

Comment: That is interesting. What distribution of Linux do you use, and what version of `top` (run `top -v`)?

Comment: If you specify `-pid` instead of `-p` but otherwise use the command I suggested, does it work?

Comment: no the whole command does not work (running it provides me with an input tick ">"), but I just checked (remote shell), it is actually a Mac OS based system (not Linx as I assumed). That would explain the pid/p differences. No version available either.

Comment: Sorry, mismatched parens. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is

1. the arg to top should be "-p" not "-pid"
2. xargs is for running non-interactive programs

Try this:

```
top -p "$(pgrep ProgramName | head -n 1)"
```

or

```
top -p "$(pgrep --oldest ProgramName)"
```

or

```
top -p "$(pgrep --newest ProgramName)"
```

Comment: +1 for `pgrep`. I'd never seen that before.

Comment: my top takes "-pid" as option, not "-p", and I don't have "pgrep" on my system, but thanks for the answer anyway!